# free(): invalid pointer error when trying to erase data from list element using free()

Tags: c, free

I am trying to complete an exercise with the following requirements:

- Create the function `ft_list_remove_if` which removes from the list, all elements
  whose data compared to `data_ref` using `cmp`, makes `cmp` return 0.
- The data from an element to be erased should be freed using `free_fct`
- Here's how it should be prototyped:

  ```
  void ft_list_remove_if(t_list **begin_list, void *data_ref, int (*cmp)(),
          void (*free_fct)(void *));
  ```
- Function pointed by `cmp` and by `free_fct` will be used as follows :

  ```
  (*cmp)(list_ptr->data, data_ref);
  (*free_fct)(list_ptr->data);
  ```

I have had no success every time I have called `free()` on the data element. It says 'free() invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)'.
Here is my code for relevant functions.

```
typedef struct llist { 
    void *a;
    struct llist *next;
} t_list;

t_list *ft_create_elem(void *data)
{
    t_list *ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    ptr-> a = data;
    ptr-> next = NULL;   /*NOTE I HAVE ANOTHER FUNCTION THAT LINKS NEWLY CREATED ELEMENT TO PREV*/
    return (ptr);
}

int ft_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
}

void *ft_list_remove_if(t_list **begin_list, void *data_ref, int (*cmp)(), void (*free_fct)(void *))
{  
    while(*begin_list)
    {
        if (cmp(((*begin_list)->a), data_ref) == 0)
            free_fct((*begin_list)->a);               
        *begin_list = (*begin_list)->next;
    }
}
```

And I call it like so:
`ft_list_remove_if(&toprint, "Third", ft_strcmp, free);`. Variable
`toprint` is  a pointer to the first element of the list of 5 that I want to navigate. (The data in each node is "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"). As per function call I am trying to delete "Third".

I would appreciate help in understanding what I am doing wrong. I am able to change the content of the `(*begin_list)->a` without an issue, however I don't know why I am unable to free the data in there. Is `(*begin_list)->a` not a valid pointer I can pass through `free()`?

Is it because in my `ft_create_elem` function I am assigning 'data' straight to `void *a`?

Would I be better off assigning `a` to the address of the data? I tried doing something like `a = &data`, but then that printed garbage...

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: The problem leading to the error when you attempt to `free()` is in the part of the code you have not shown: the pointer you are trying to free is not one that was previously returned by `malloc()`.  As a separate matter, your `ft_list_remove_if()` function only frees the data -- it does not remove the node containing it from the list, nor free the node (though it's not clear from the spec that the node itself should be freed).  Also, the function destroys the caller's pointer to the list, even when none of the nodes should be removed.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger I need to retain the node as I understand it. I understand I will destroy the callers pointer to the list so I will introduce a temp variable to maintain it or process the changes.                                                                                                         
As far as the pointer to free is concerned, in the function ft_create_elem I have tried to assign the "void *data" to a pointer on which I have called malloc  but it yields the same 'free() invalid pointer' result when I execute ft_list_remove_if. Here it is

Comment: ``` 
t_list *ft_create_elem(void *data)
{
    t_list *ptr;

    ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    ptr-> a = malloc(sizeof(data));
    ptr ->a = data;
    ptr-> next = NULL;
    return (ptr);
} ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to `free` the data in the list node, but the data itself is not being dynamically allocated by `malloc`, so you can't use `free` on it.

To fix this, you can either change the way you are storing the data in the list so that it is dynamically allocated, or you can change your remove function to simply remove the node from the list without freeing the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response @underthevoid I have tried this if I have understood your suggestion correctly but same error... 

```                                                                  
    t_list *ft_create_elem(void *data)
{
    char *dtaptr;
    t_list *ptr;
    
    ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    dtaptr = malloc(sizeof(data));
    dtaptr = data;
    ptr-> a = dtaptr;
    ptr-> next = NULL;
    return (ptr);
}
```